# Search Directory and sub-directories for list of strings and pipe item numbers to text file

Tags: xml, batch-file

I have directories that contain [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) files which have item numbers contained within them that need to be piped to a text file on my desktop.

The only way I can search for these items is by the order number `<OrderNum>ORDER123</OrderNum>`, which is also inside these XML files. There can be multiple items in each file that are in the form of `<Item>ITEM1XYZ</Item>`.

I am able to pipe all of the text in these files to results.txt on my desktop. I have tried including the `For` command with `Findstr` but I am not able to get my desired results. The below code is the closest I have come:

```
findstr /I /R /G:%userprofile%\desktop\orderlist.txt "E:\Program Files\Output\Original Data Files\*.XML" >> %userprofile%\desktop\results.txt
```

`Orderlist.txt` is a list of order numbers e.g. `ORDER123`, `ORDER456`, `ORDER789`. `Results.txt` should list all of the item numbers `ITEM1XYZ`, `ITEM2WXY`, `ITEM3ZYX` contained within the desired `.xml` files.

Here is my example xml content, with sensitive information removed:

````
<?xml version="1.0"?><productListing title="Our Products"><product><name>Product One</name><ordernum>ORDER123</ordernum><item>ORDER789</item><description>Product One is an exciting new item which will simplify your life.</description><cost>$19.95</cost><shipping>$2.95</shipping></product><product><name>Product Two</name></product><product><name>Product Three</name><ordernum>ORDER123</ordernum><item>ITEM3ZYX</item><description>This is such a fantastic item which you will recommend to all of your friends.</description><cost>$24.95</cost><shipping>$2.95</shipping></product><productListing>```
````

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56599848/edit) to include sufficient content from your [tag:xml] file to aid us to help you parse it appropriately?

Comment: I cannot give you specific details as it has customer information.  Is there something in particular that I can give you? The lengths of the files are different in size so I cannot just look at a specific line for the item.

Comment: I have added some example [tag:xml] content to your question for you to modify as required or replace as necessary. As you can see, it shouldn't be too difficult for you to insert your specific element names and attributes so that we can replicate your content sufficiently to offer potential solutions. Make sure that you provide the root and child node elements, if your required information is nested further than shown. **After you have modified the XML content, please remove the emboldened text from your question, so that we're aware that you're satisfied with the provided information.**

Comment: It would also be an idea to specify what information you wish to retrieve from the data - as an example listing derived from our posted data example

Comment: Compo, I should state that this is my very first post on Stackflow and that I have no experience in writing XML.  I am sorry for my lack of experience but we have to start somewhere to get better. When I open the XML file in Notepad++, it is all in one line like I edited yours. Can't this file be searched as if it was a txt file?  Probably showing my lack of experience with dumb a question.

Comment: batch is the worst choice to process XML files. Although it's possible *if the XML format doesn't change at all*, I really recommend anything other. Is Powershell an option?

Comment: It is possible that your XML was produced using Unix line endings instead of Windows ones and your chosen text editor may not be configured to show it correctly. If your content is in one line then quite frankly it shouldn't be, XML is supposed to be both human and machine readable, and that isn't. Anyhow, back to your task, can you please explain exactly what you're expecting the script to output, given your input order numbers, _as already requested by @Magoo_. As you've not modified the XML content any provided any answers will need modifying by you afterwards.